# Remove crafting recipes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make the carrot on a stick crafting recipe disabled. Is there an easy way to do this? Also, I want it for a specific world.

(Snapshot 19w34a)

Comment: What did you try yourself so far? This seems like a "do the work for me" post. I recommend reading the [tour] to understand this website better.

Comment: I looked through all of the .minecraft files and couldn't find the crafting recipes, so I am asking for help. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this website about asking questions and having people answer it for you?

Comment: Is it, but we also expect people to try their projects themselves first and only ask about details when they're stuck. Googling the four words from your title gives me multiple results that contain the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely easy through use of a datapack. Simply put a blank JSON file in the recipes folder called "carrot_on_a_stick" and the recipe will fail to load (only the specified recipe, not the datapack) and effectively be removed from the game.

Plus, Datapacks are also world specific!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could have a repeating command block execute this command:

```
/clear @a minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick
```

Once a carrot on a stick is obtained it will instantly be cleared from the player's inventory.

Comment: This, unfortunately, is likely not what the poster was looking for. There are plenty of situations where you want the item to be obtained in a special way instead of crafting, so just clearing it wouldnt help

Answer (score -1):

Adding/removing recipes isn't something vanilla Minecraft supports. There are no configuration files with recipes. You'd need a mod. I'd suggest CraftTweaker, but there's no 1.15 version.